# JavaFX TextField changing padding to 0 on focus

Tags: java, javafx, padding, textfield

I'm trying to set a padding to a textfield in JavaFX (using Java 8_192).
I've got a simple VBox with 3 TextFields in it. If i manually set the padding on the first TextField, the other TextFields are somehow resetting their padding to 0 when i focus them.

The first TextField has a manual padding:

[image: screenshot-1]

When focusing the second (or the third) TextField, they get a padding of 0:

[image]

If i focus something different, their padding will be reset to the usual padding set by javafx (4, 7, 4, 7). The strange thing is, if i set the padding of `tf2` instead of `tf1`, there won't be any problem.
Also, if i manually set the padding of every TextField, they won't be reset to 0. But this obviously can't be an answer...

My code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        TextField tf3 = new TextField();

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf1);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf3);

        tf1.setPadding(new Insets(7, 7, 7, 7));
        // Setting the padding of tf2 instead of tf1 works

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Why is the padding being reset after focus, only when setting the padding to the first TextField i add to the vbox?

Comment: I have reproduced the issue on Java 8 as well. Side note when using `.addAll(..)` you should add all of them not just one or just use `.add(...)`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in JavaFX 12.0.1. Setting the padding via `setStyle("-fx-padding: 7px;")` appears to be a workaround.

Comment: That seems to work. Unfortunately, i'm using textField.paddingProperty().bind(...) to bind the padding to some specific value. I'd have to do it the other way around, set a change listener to my value and manually set the style. Not that optimal though.

Comment: You may want to [submit a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) if one doesn't [already exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8213225?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: Definitely this is a bug. The whole issue is related to CSS and pseudoClasses state changes. The reset to padding 0 happens at [CsssStyleHelper](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/CssStyleHelper.java#L731). This [comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8127435?focusedCommentId=13749085&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13749085) really explains what is going on. Your failing case won't happen if the first node is not focused.

Comment: Hmm, this is a possible workaround: just add `tf1.getStyleClass().add("tf1");` to your code. Even if you don't have a CSS stylesheet applied or if you don't add anything to it, it looks like it solves the issue. Again, it is related to the complex logic that is applied in CssStyleHelper.

Comment: Thank you. With that workaround, i can still easily bind my `paddingProperty`. I'll have a look at the bug reports later and report it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you just want to set the padding of a textfield when it is focused like in the title, then I would use this:

```java
yourTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
        if (newPropertyValue) {
            System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
    
            yourTextField.setStyle("-fx-padding: *yourNewPadding*");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Textfield out focus");

            yourTextField.setStyle("-fx-padding: *yourOldPadding*");
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps you!
Sorry if this doesn't answer your question but this is how I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an object-oriented programming language. Most code is setting stuff for that object. The easiest (and most practical in most cases) solution is to manually set the padding for the objects.

On another note, VBox.addAll(Node...) allows you to pass many objects, not just one. If you need to only pass one, use VBox.add(Node);